# Deploying EJB on openEJB

Tags: openejb

Can someone help me with the process of deploying EJB application on TOMEE server (OpenEJB standalone server)? Is it simply dropping EJB application jar in the common library folder (apps folder) of the server? 
How does TOMEE bind EJBs to JNDI names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TomEE follows JavaEE6 naming for JNDI names.

To deploy a war put it like for tomcat in webapps/ folder and for ejbmodules or ears create a apps/ folder to put them there and uncomment the Deployments line in conf/tomee.xml.